# Changing paragraph selection style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textselection

I'm kind of new to JQuery, and I'm in a very difficult position right now.
I need to make the user free to write in a paragraph, and then change the text color as he wish, but only a selected text from his paragraph, like text editing in a browser.
Here are my files : 
**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-5589-1" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_ext.css">
   <title>Editable Paragraph</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p contenteditable="true" class="par" id="txt">This is an editable paragraph.</p>
   <center>
           <button type="button" id="redText">Color text in red</button>
   </center>
   <center>
           <button type="button" id="blueText">Color text in blue</button>
   </center>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pushred.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.par {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #A3A3A3
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#redText').click(function() {
    change_color('red');
});


$('#blueText').click(function() {
    change_color('blue');
});

function change_color(theColor) {
    //What should I put here to make any selected text change the color ?
}
```

**Important information : i don't want the entire paragraph to change, only a segment, a selection, like in text editors**

Comment: I googled up http://api.jquery.com/select/ . It says > This event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes. > The method for retrieving the current selected text differs from one browser to another. A number of jQuery plug-ins offer cross-platform solutions.

Comment: Yes I found the same thing, but what i want is not only retrieving the text, I want to apply a style to it, bold, underlining, etc... and it shouldn't be an input, because i'll be sending 5 or 6 paragraphs as a plain HTML, in other words, i want to make a simple text editor.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#redText').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
};
```